# Eclipse Java WeightedQuickUnionUF

Tags: java, data-structures, union-find

Currently working in Eclipse on a problem. 
Data stucture weightedQuickUnionFind

What I have:

-a list of data in a separate .txt file which contains ID's of users. example:

0     5

0     2

1     3

1     2

2     5

3     7

What this is basically saying is that users of ID 0 is connected in a social network with users of an ID of 5 and so on. if 0 is connected to 2, and 1 is connected to 2, then 0 is connected to 2. Hope that's clear.
Anyway, with this list, I have written a Main class and a WeightedUnionFind Class. In my main class I have shelled out several methods that will help me to answer the questions:

1. How many people are connected to each individual, (ie. how many people are connected to 0), and how many have no connections?
2. How many groups of ID's are connected and what is the largest group?

I don't want to flood this with question after question, so I'm just looking for a start off point.

Like I said I've only shelled out the methods so far, and just need a starting point to implement these methods on the .txt file.

```
 /**
 *numberOfIndividuals() method Finds # of distinct individual in data
 *ie. how many users are there?
 */

 public static int numberOfIndividuals() 
 {
    return -1;
    // not implemented yet
 }

 /**
 * Get the number of distinctly connected groups of individuals.
 *
 */
 public static int numberOfGroups() 
 {
    return -1;
    // not implemented yet
 }
```

I have written a separate class called

```
 public class WeightedQuickUnionUF {
      //which I incorporate the methods find, count, union etc.
 }
```

Hope this was clear.

Comment: Are you asking for implementation?

Comment: yes, just looking for a starting point on implementation. I've read the chapter on this and watched multiple youtube videos and it hasn't gotten any clearer on how to implement these methods.